# Add a button to float on top of a ViewController, Path inspired

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to build a button that will be floating on top of a ViewController, it should remain in the same position statically while the viewcontroller beneath it can scroll up and down.

I designed my own button class and in the viewdidload of the parent Viewcontroller I am doing this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad// this is the parent viewcontroller
 {
[super viewDidLoad];
customButton *floatingButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:(self.view.frame)];
[floatingButton setLocation:CGPointMake(300, 430)];
[self.view addSubview:floatingButton];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:floatingButton];
```

This is not doing it, as in when I run the button doesn't show up, only the view controller.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where are you adding this button? You should add this on top of viewcontroller.

Comment: I think I am doing this, as in I am doing [self.view addSubview:floatingButton]. is that not correct? should I use another method to do this?

Comment: So is that inside the child view controllers, viewDidLoad method?

Comment: no that is the parent ViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, but the error was on my end, I wasn't initializing the frame properly, so the button was there but had a height and width of (0,0).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you're initializing your button properly. initWithFrame is a UIView initializer, being called by a regular UIButton. I don't see how you would get anything but an empty view here.

If you have a custom initializer for your custom button you should use

```
[[CustomButton alloc] myCustomInitializerWithFrame:frame];
```

Comment: hi, I actually can live without the custom initialization. This is not the issue.

Comment: what happens if you set the background color of your button to black, for example. Would you see it being added? Maybe comment our the setLocation method as well, since I don't know what that does.